# How to read file line by line in unix with lines > 256 chars

Tags: unix

I would like to read a unix file line by line and store the value of the line into a variable. Just like this:

```
while read line
do
        echo $line
done < my_file.txt
```

It works, but the variable $line will only contain the first 256 characters of the string. So on long strings this doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea how to read long lines?

Comment: I don't think there is an arbitraty limit, even if so, it cannot be that small.  What environment are you in?

Comment: The environment is a SunOS 5.11 11.2 sun4v sparc sun4v (result of uname -a)

Comment: try using `usr/xpg4/bin/ksh` (Been years since I've been on a Sun, I think that is the right path). I hope you're not really constrained to using `/bin/sh`. OR consider reogranizing your task under `/usr/nawk`. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately I am constrained to using /bin/ksh

Comment: does `echo ${.sh.version}` return anything?